# Spark write to S3 with 'partitionBy()'; but not have column name (just value) in S3 directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a bucket in AWS S3 called 's3a://devices'

I am trying to write a dataframe to it, based on Company name using code below.

```
df = df.withColumn("companyname_part", df["companyname"])
df.repartition("companyname_part").dropDuplicates().write.mode("append").partitionBy("companyname_part").parquet('s3a://devices/')
```

I have a few questions relate to this storage and daily incremental code above.

1. If I pull all present data daily and want to overwrite and drop duplicates daily, should I change the above code to run daily with "overwrite"? And previous incarnations of the S3 buckets will be overwritten for each Partition?
2. Is there a "HDFS" command that I could automate, or possibly something I could use in the PySpark script through os.command/subprocess to get ride of the "companyname_part=" portion of the directories, so that it just reads the value after "=". I am worried that all partitions starting with the same text will make Athena queries slower.
3. Does anyone have feedback/advice on Optimal partitioning for S3? I am using this partition column because it will be a lookup for an API. But I'm curious about optimal Sizing (megabytes) of Partitions. And is 5000 too many?

Comment: any solutions so far?